# have a progress bar in winform to show the time taken for the encryption of file c#

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, progress-bar

Currently my application is doing encryption of files and folder and i trying to have a progress bar to make the application a nicer interface and also to have know how long it take to encrypt.

However this is my first time using progress bar and i kinda confuse with all the terms mention such as background worker,steps,maximum etc. was wondering anyone know how to create and set a simple version of progress bar. thanks in advance .

AFTER see-ing swordfish suggestion and trying it out..here the code i have

this is the part of my code based on the link provided and i tried it
and the part where i used part of the code to the button

```
      public LockPasswordBox(IFile[] info)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ifile = info;

    // To report progress from the background worker we need to set this property
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    // This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    // This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
}


// On worker thread so do our thing!
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Your background task goes here
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        // Report progress to 'UI' thread
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        // Simulate long task
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
// Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // The progress percentage is a property of e
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

button code

```
    private void lockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the background worker
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Problem facing is..after i press the button.it just straight pop out the message box encryption success.

Comment: That might be a bit problematic, as unless you're writing the code that actually does the data transforms, you're going to have a difficult time figuring out where the encryption is at any point in time.

Comment: The MSDN article on ProgressBar should give you more information on steps, maximum coz they are the properties of this class. Kindly google.

Comment: LOL...ya googling...cause i nvr use a progress bar before and dun realli know how to start though

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Minimun = 1`, `Maximum = 100` and `Step = 1` you need to call `PerformStep()` 99 times for the progressbar to complete.

If you can not get accurate information from `lControl.Encrypt(details)` about how far the operation is gone you can not know when to update all those steps on your progressbar.

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) has a simple example on how to get the progressbar moving.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar requirement and this helped me with my task. Hope it will help you too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Its quiet simple actually all you have to do is report the progress from the background worker using the not so mysterious reportprogress method and have a method to update the progress bar when ever the progress is reported.

Try to implement it this way and if you hit a road block post your code.

Comment: currently the loading bar did run....but...it run before i even click on my button..i followed the instruction inside and well it kinda work but not really what i need cause i wan it to load when i clicked the button not before

Comment: well you cant expect it to work out of the box for each and every kind of requirement. Use it as an implementation guide and tweak it to your need. If codes from net work right away for everyone then wats the need of programmers!!!